# Websocket pushes the image to the web side, too many canvas rendering causes the page to crash

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I use python to get images from the camera, and then push each frame of image to the web through websocket. The fps is 60-70. I think this caused the canvas to refresh and finally hangs.

I hope to get your answer, how should I protect the memory and remove the garbage in time?

[I will receive two images at the same time for each frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f7p4.png)

[This is the result of the google dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23cn1.png)

Comment: *"I hope to get your answer"* What other methods have you tried and what research have you done to find the reason for your problem?

Comment: It seems to me you do actually want to send a video through the internet. Maybe you could use something like ffmpeg to combine the cameras images and then send the video

Comment: Try improving your canvas performance like batching canvas changes and pre-rendering.
This guide will help - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Comment: @NewToJS  Hi, I tried to control fps from python, probably stable at 20fps, the page won't get stuck, and the video will be smoother. So I feel that it will be a out of memory problem.  but I can't reduce the fps in the production environment